# Why can't I use .sort independently of .map inside a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to sort an array of objects by a particular property and render an `<Entry />` component for each one, in the correct order. The complication is that I need to place a different one-off component directly after the first `<Entry />`. So I need to do things in this order: 1 - Sort the array. 2 - Render the first `<Entry />` followed by the one-off component. 3 - Map through the remaining sorted array and render the rest of the `<Entry />`s.

But React isn't letting me use `.sort` independently of `.map`.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
render() {
return (
    <React.Fragment> 
        {entries.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)}

        <Entry entryNumber={entries[0].id} />

        <OneOffComponent />

        {entries.map((entry, index) => {
          if (index > 0) {
            return <Entry entryNumber={entry.id} />
          }
        }}
    </React.Fragment> 
);
}
```

But this code gives me an error: "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {entryId, text, likes, user, date}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: `entries.map(entry, index){` for me this is syntax error. Make sure to paste here correct code and update question.

Comment: I might already have an answer to your question - react components require to have one root element - not plenty of elements one after another - it's react architecture concept for performance reasons.

Comment: @Zydnar I forgot to enclose the arguments in parentheses. I updated the question.

Comment: The syntax is still wrong. The `=>` of the arrow syntax is missing.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, I updated the code in my question. This isn't the cause of my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things off with your code:

- Variables assignment should be performed before returning the ReactElement.
- A ReactElement should be returned in the render function, not an array.
  This could be a React.Fragment, a HTML element, or a React component containing zero or more React Elements.

You can unpack the array to pick out the entry among the rest after it's sorted.

```
render() {
  // say you have entries array from props, state or where ever  ¯_(ツ)_/¯
  entries.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)
  const [firstEntry, ...rest] = entries;
  const restEntries = rest.map(
     entry => <Entry key={entry.id} entryNumber={entry.id} />
  );

  return (
    <React.Fragment> 
      <Entry entryNumber={firstEntry.id} />
      <OneOffComponent />
      {restEntries}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm limited here not knowing where entries is declared in your program. I have commented where in the code you would sort entries.

Comment: Instead `¯_(ツ)_/¯` shold be `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` you get fired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your `map` function only returning something conditionally. This will cause every entry with `index <= 0` to stay as they are in your array followed by React trying to render them.

If your condition is not met, you should send out an empty node instead (I do not know if a fragment will work) :

```
render() {
    entries.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes) //Does the exact same thing

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Entry entryNumber={entries[0].id} />

            <OneOffComponent />
            {entries.map((entry, index) => index > 0 ? 
                <Entry key={entry.id} entryNumber={entry.id} /> 
                : 
                <div key={entry.id}/>)
            }
        }}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

An even better solution would be to use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to take the first value out of your array. Since it will also remove the first value from your array, you do not need your condition anymore :

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {entries.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)}

            <Entry entryNumber={entries.shift().id} />

            <OneOffComponent />
            {entries.map(({ id }) => <Entry key={id} entryNumber={id} />)}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: I really like the `shift` idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `sort()` also *returns* the sorted array, and so it is like you are outputting that array of objects within a `<React.Fragment>` element:

```
<React.Fragment> 
    {entries.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes)}
```

The sorting itself is not the problem, the place where you do it, is. So move that sorting out of the output:

```
entries.sort((a, b) => b.likes - a.likes);
return (
    <React.Fragment>
```

That will fix it.

NB: Instead of the `if` inside the `map` callback, just skip the first element with `slice`:

```
entries.slice(1).map( ......
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer got a down vote. It helped. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know either why it was downvoted. *shrug*. More important is it to hear it was of use to you ;-)